# Why did some of my fruit trees not grow to the next stage?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In the picture below, I have separated my trees with 2 horizontal spaces and 1 vertical space from the next tree. They are all non-native trees and were planted on the same day. (The holes are for spatial reference and were not there while the trees were left for one night)

[image: ACNH Tree Plantation]

Why did the trees in the middle region not grow? The trees on the edges advanced to the next growth stage while those in the middle of the plantation pattern did not. Is there a probability where they fail to advance? Or is there a maximum number of plants that will advance to the next stage in a day? (Because I did plant a whole lot of trees and maybe I exceeded some maximum number?)

Answer (score 3):

If there at 12 or more other trees (stunted, growing, or fully grown) in the 9x9 grid surrounding the tree, the tree will not grow.

For example the stunted tree near your head has 12 other trees trying to grow around it:
[image: 12 numbered trees in the 9x9 grid around a stunted tree in ACNH]

To get your trees to grow properly you need to space them out more.

Alternately you can grow them elsewhere and then move them into this pattern.   Trees won't grow this packed together, but if placed fully grown into this configuration they will still produce fruit, wood, and other tree resources.

Source: https://gamewith.net/animal-crossing-new-horizons/article/show/18578

Comment: This table (consider using markdown table for this instead of a code block) shows 11 growing trees, but the answer says 12 or more... should there be 1 more capitalized T?

Comment: Ah, I forgot they do require headers. Best one can do would be something that renders like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaP65.png

Comment: I replaced the badly formatted table with an image.

Answer (score -1):

It's not just the spacing you have to worry about, the trees in the middle section aren't growing because of an issue where they're not getting enough sunlight. New Leaf also had this quirk. Move the trees to a different area and plant only one row at a time to avoid this.

Comment: This answer doesn't give a lot of detail or cite any sources, but it is essentially correct.